# ckeditor4 codesnippet plugin - dialogue is not showing

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, highlight.js

I installed the codesnippet plugin by copying the files in the plugins folder
I added codesnippet to the extra plugins line in include.php:

```
$ckeditor->config['extraPlugins'] = 'codesnippet,droplets,pagelink,shybutton,justify,colorbutton';
```

The plugin icon shows up in the editor, but when I click it the darkened background of the plugins dialogue appears only for a blink, than nothing happens.

As supposed in the ckeditor forum I even added the lines

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/codesnippet/lib/highlight/styles/googlecode.css" />
<script src="/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/codesnippet/lib/highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

to the header of my theme and checked the paths, which are ok, but nothing helps.

Does anynone have an idea what could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the folder /dialogs/ in my plugins/codesnippet folder was missing. Now everything works fine.